# Calling jQuery function after click on some element

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, jquery-events

Here is the HTML code:

```
<p onclick='javascript:func(this);'>Bla bla bla</p>
```

and here is the script (it is written in the head of the document):

```
function func(e) {
  var t = e.text();
  console.log(t);
}
```

It doesn't work and I don't understand why. The error message is:

> "Object # has no method 'text'".

Comment: I don't see any jQuery.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Wrap it in the jQuery wrapper. `.text()` is a jQuery method, and your element `e` is a plain Javascript DOM element, so you need the jQuery wrapper.

```
var t = $(e).text();
```

Side note: unobtrusive event handler assignments are preferred to inline handlers. For example:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('p').click(function(){
        var t = $(this).text();
        console.log(t);
    });
});
```

The above uses jQuery to assign the click handler (instead of inline Javascript) and so because of that, the element can be accessed in `this` for the plain Javascript object, or `$(this)` for the jQuery object.

Answer (score 0):

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/XYnuJ/)

This is plain javascript and will do what you ask for.

```
function func(e) {
  var t = e.innerHTML;
  console.log(t);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using `innerHTML`:

```
function func(e) {
    var t= e.innerHTML;
    console.log(t);
}
```

Comment: Sorry if you were just about to edit it yourself, but it was in the LQP review list ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Use `innerText` if you do not use jquery.

```
function func(e) {
  var t = e.innerText;
  console.log(t);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Right way is:

**HTML:**

```
<p onclick='func(this);'>Bla bla bla</p>
```

instead of

```
<p onclick='javascript:func(this);'>Bla bla bla</p>
```

**Javascript:**

```
function func(e) {
    var t = e.innerHTML;
    console.log(t);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Jquery is designed to be unobtrusive. If your adding onclick attributes everywhere your doing it wrong.

Instead you should be adding event listeners

```
<p>Blah Blah Blah</p>
```

Jquery/Script

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('p').on('click', function(){
        console.log($(this).text());
    });
});
```